# Java TreeMap returns null for key when value exists

Tags: java, comparator, treemap

I've created a TreeMap like this:

```
   Map<Date, List<MyInput>> inputsByDate = new TreeMap<>(new Comparator<Date>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Date lhs, Date rhs) {
            return dateUtil.compareDay(lhs, rhs);
        }


    });
```

My method in the comparator is not pretty but at least identifies similarity(I'm not using HashMap with equals and hash due to other reasons):

```
public int compareDay(Date lhs, Date rhs) {
    Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal1.setTime(lhs);
    cal2.setTime(rhs);
    boolean sameDay = cal1.get(Calendar.YEAR) == cal2.get(Calendar.YEAR) &&
            cal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) == cal2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
    if (sameDay) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Anyway, the problem is the snippet below. The last element is null when I retrieve it.

```
public List<MyType> convert(Map<Date, List<MyInput>> inputByDate, Map<Date, Boolean> isDoneByDate) {
        List<MyType> result = Lists.newArrayList();
        for (Date dateKey : inputByDate.keySet()) {
            boolean isDone = false;
            Boolean res = isDoneByDate.get(dateKey);
            if (res != null) {
                isDone = res;
            }
            List<MyInput> inputs = inputByDate.get(dateKey);

            MyType retrieved=new MyType(dateKey, inputs, isDone);
            result.add(retrieved);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

When I run the last snippet with the debugger I can clearly see that there are (as an example) 3 keys with values that are not null. I must be missing something here because I cannot see how reports can be null if I have validated that each key is matched with a valid pair before. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The comparator needs to determine <, ==, >, not just == and !=. That is negative 0 or positive return value. Check the docs for comparators. -1 means lhs < rhs.

Comment: Btw, do you mean `inputByDate.keySet()` instead of `inputByDate()`? And what is `reportsByDay`?

Comment: My bad, my "obfuscation" that I applied on my actual code was faulty. Corrected now.

Comment: It must be the case that `compareDay(a, b) == -compareDay(b, a)` but you never `return +1`

Comment: Got it, thanks. Knew that this would be a sup optimal solution but I didn't fully get that it would break the map. Just though sorting would suck. Fixing comparator solved it.

Comment: A cleaner solution would be to use `Map<LocalDate, List<MyInput>> inputsByDate = new TreeMap<>();` as `LocalDate` is only the date not time.

Comment: Note also that if the values used as keys contain any time information,  i.e. the time is not 00:00:00 (or a consistent value) in _all_ keys, this will break as the comparator will return "equal" for two instances with the same date but different times.  This design leaves you open to future really-hard-to-debug problems where map values mysteriously disappear and get replaced by other values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the dates are different your comparator should return -1 *or* 1 since it has to be symmetric, i.e. if you return -1 when comparing `date1` and `date2` you have to return 1 when comparing `date2` and `date1`. Your code is bound to break the map since it can't reliably determine an order for the keys.

So refactor your `compare()` to something like this:

```
int result = Integer.compare( cal1.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal2.get(Calendar.YEAR));
if( result == 0 ) { //if the year is equal compare the days
  result = Integer.compare( cal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR), cal2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));
}
return result;
```

Edit: A small breakdown on what probably happened with your comparator.

If you have a look at the sources you'll see that the map will compare the new key with the already existing keys. Your comparator would thus order them according to insert order, i.e. since you always return -1 for non-equal keys the map will always follow the left branch and thus the last added element will be the "smallest". That's just another problem though.

The problem you're facing is to be found in the `getEntryUsingComparator()` method which is called indirectly by `get(key)`. The method looks like this:

```
Comparator<? super K> cpr = comparator;
if (cpr != null) {
  Entry<K,V> p = root;
  while (p != null) {
    int cmp = cpr.compare(k, p.key);
    if (cmp < 0)
      p = p.left;
    else if (cmp > 0)
      p = p.right;
    else
      return p;
  }
}
return null;
```

As you can see due to always returning -1 the method would always execute the `cmp < 0` branch until `p = p.left` results in `p = null` because there is no more left element and then the while loop is terminated and you end up at `return null;`.

Comment: I was aware of the comparator not being symmetrical but I figured "fuck it, I'll never have more than 10 keys in this map anyway.". That was a bad move because now it is working.